My css gallery images are going lower than expected when entering a row of images underneath the first one (SOLVED)
I found a CSS gallery code, and wanted to try running it on my own to see if it actually worked. The code is Moodboard with Masonry by shinya1992 on codepen. I copy and pasted all the code and ran it, and I expected the result I'd see in the preview of the previously linked code (a well spaced gallery). This was not what appeared.
I did get a gallery of images, but there's a disproportionate amount of space between the first image and the one in the row underneath it, and there's no space between the images.
I tried to copy and paste all the code involved in the original code to my best ability to see if this was merely an issue with the way I'd put down the code, but after testing, I don't think that's the case. Even so, here is the code I have copy and pasted (using only 8 images as an example):


var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
  }); 
});
*{ box-sizing: border-box;}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
/*   background: #cc6633; */
  font: 12px 'Montserrat', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
}
.title {
  color: #7d3917;
  font-size: 46px;
  margin: 10px 0 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 24%;
}
.gutter-sizer {
  width: 1.3333%;
}


.grid-item {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 1.3333%;
  position: relative;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.itm-from {
  background: #cc6633;
  background: rgba(204, 102, 51, 0.7);
  color: #fdfdfd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s opacity ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s opacity ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s opacity ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s opacity ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid-item:hover .itm-from {
  opacity: 1;
}
.itm-from a {
  color: #7d3917;
  display: block;
}
@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  .grid-sizer, 
  .grid-item {
    width: 32%;
  }
  .gutter-sizer {
    width: 2%;
  }
  .grid-item {
    margin-bottom: 2%;
  }
  #pdesc { line-height: 1.5; }
}
@media all and ( max-width: 700px) {
  .grid-sizer, 
  .grid-item {
    width: 48%;
  }
  .gutter-sizer {
    width: 4%;
  }
  .grid-item {
    margin-bottom: 4%;
  }
}
@media all and ( max-width: 400px ) {
  .grid-sizer, 
  .grid-item {
    width: calc(100%);
  }
}
<div class='title'>Moodboard with Masonry</div>
<div class='grid'>
 <div class='grid-sizer'></div>
  <div class='gutter-sizer'></div>
  <!-- C+P BELOW FOR NEW ADDITIONS
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='imgurl'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  ---------------------------------->
  
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='https://farm1.staticflickr.com/149/428144742_f509cd9927.jpg'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='https://farm1.staticflickr.com/204/489660321_a6833ba9cf.jpg'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='https://farm1.staticflickr.com/244/459042039_98a488bf79.jpg'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='https://farm1.staticflickr.com/27/92937010_2d03825900.jpg'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='https://farm1.staticflickr.com/637/31711772564_f0a9627692.jpg'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='https://farm1.staticflickr.com/73/154716528_717697a157.jpg'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='https://farm1.staticflickr.com/77/199628917_e19e3ff68d.jpg'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='grid-item'>
    <img src='https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1029/1144531870_5b1119763b_z.jpg?zz&'>
    <div class='itm-from'>
      from <a href='#'>blahblah</a>
    </div>
  </div>



I've seen the same code sampled in other places with no issues.
I'm curious if this code requires an active site to display properly or something like that? Or its a problem with the image size?
EDIT: This was a problem on my end! As you'll find a commenter mentioned below, I didn't get the jQuery library required to run the element nor the full Masonry script placed within the gear icon above the JS section of the code, causing the code to not display the way it did in the Codepen because it didn't have all the required elements it needed to run. When I ran the code after inputting all the required scripts, it worked perfectly. I appreciate the help very much!

Hello:)
It seems that the issue is because the images are in different sizes. Try to use CSS to make the images smaller

so that link doesn't demonstrate the issue?

@AdamBasha - that's what masonry layout deals with - different sized content elements

If you click on the gear icon in the JS tab on CodePen, you'll see that the Pen links to the jQuery library, the Masonry script and one other script. You need all those too for it to work!

@ralph.m ah, thank you!!! im very unfamiliar with jquery so i wasnt aware that was a requirement!! i'll keep this in mind next time i see a piece of code like the one linked above :0)
